# How to make Ubuntu Switcher bring to front windows while I'm holding "Alt+Tab"?

Tags: unity, application-switcher

Is there a way to have the instant "Bring-to-Front" feature under Ubuntu while "Alt+Tab" are being hold? Just as it is under you know which OS.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you want by *instant "Bring-to-Front"*? And *Just as it is under you know which OS*?

Comment: As it is under Windows 7: when "alt+tab" are hit, almost immediately the next app window is brought to the front (above all other open windows) without letting the "alt+tab" keys.

Comment: This behavior is used in Ubuntu as well. So, you want to say that when you press Alt+Tab nothing is happen?

Comment: No, I mean without needing the keys to be let.

Comment: http://www.windows7taskforce.com/uploads/Super%20Alt-Tab.png

Comment: On this picture "alt+tab" are still being hold and you see the next app window above the others (which become transperant). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable **Shift Switcher** plugin from [**CompizConfig Settings Manager** [image: Install CompizConfig Settings Manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/). The default key combination is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Supe</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, but you can change this combination as you wish. It looks something like this:

[image: Shift Switcher]

[[Click on image to enlarge]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1UMr.png)

Also, using **CompizConfig Settings Manager** you have many other options in this sense. Just test them and choose what you like.

Comment: Many thanks! However, is that mean there's no way to do sth like this without 3d party plugins?

Comment: Thanks again! I was going to do that after your final comment anyway :) Thanks, Radu!

Answer (score 0):

I've filed a bug report about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1239092